# Calculate cosine similarity for vectors between two pandas columns?

Tags: python-3.x, cosine-similarity

I have the following Pandas Dataframe and need to find the cosine similarity by row. but my code returns a matrix of values.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [[0.1, 0.2],[0.5,0.3,0.3],[0.5]], "b" : [[0.1,0.2],[0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.5]]})

cosine_similarity(df["a"].tolist(), df["b"].tolist())
```

I need to have an output with an extra column and a cosine value for each row.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to calculate the cosine similarity for each row between the value of column `a` and column `b` it is easier to use [cosine distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) and substract the result [from 1 to get the cosine similarity](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/cosdist.htm).

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

df['cosine'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 - cosine(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
                 a                b    cosine
0       [0.1, 0.2]       [0.1, 0.2]  1.000000
1  [0.5, 0.3, 0.3]  [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]  0.877866
2            [0.5]            [0.5]  1.000000
```