# Cosine similarity between columns of two different DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I wanted to compute the cosine similarity between two DataFrame(for a different sizes) and store the result in the new data. The similarity is calculated using BERT embeddings

```
 df1
title
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

df2
claim
fact checked claims one
fact checked claims tweet

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
df_1['title_embeddings']=df_1['title'].apply(lambda x: model.encode(x))
df_2['claim_embeddings']=df_2['claim'].apply(lambda x: model.encode(x))

sim_score=[]
text =[]
for i in range(len(df['claim_embeddings'])):
   t=df['title_embeddings'].apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x, df['claim_embeddings'][i]))
   sim_score.append(t)
   text.append(claim_embeddings'][i])
```

Current error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

Expected output

```
df
title                       claims                  sim score
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fact checked claims one    0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fact checked claims one    0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fact checked claims one    0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fact checked claims tweet   0  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fact checked claims tweet   0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet fact checked claims tweet   0
```

I have tried [Calculate cosine similarity for vectors between two pandas columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599092/calculate-cosine-similarity-for-vectors-between-two-pandas-columns) but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You can probably do something like `cosine_similarity(df_1['title_embeddings'].to_numpy()[:, None], df_2['claim_embeddings'].to_numpy()` to get a similarity matrix for all possible combinations.

Comment: Also gives error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Here `array.reshape(1, -1)` must be used as you are comparing only for a single sample. For example `cosine_similarity(x.reshape(1,-1),y.reshape(1,-1))`

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
title=df['title'].tolist()
claim=df['claim'].tolist()
title=model.encode(title)
claim=model.encode(claim)
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity(title[0].reshape(1,-1),claim[0].reshape(1,-1))
```

Comment: it didn't resolve the issue of  n*m mapping, BTW thanks

Comment: Are you saying that it dint work for all title*claim?

Comment: It worked but was unable to loop for title[0] and claim[0], any solution?